# Can there be a varying matrix A for a linear transformation based on domain elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

My question is based on an exercise in the introductory textbook for linear algebra titled "Linear Algebra and its Applications, 4th ed." by David C. Lay. It can be found in Chapter 4, Section 4.2, and is #33. Please note that I am a beginning undergraduate math major and this is my first question on the site; my notation and definitions may not be proper in some cases- apologies in advance!

$\rule{400pt}{.4pt}$

Here is the exercise, for reference:

Let $M_{2\times2}$ be the vector space of all $2\times2$ matrices, and define $T : M_{2\times2} \rightarrow M_{2\times2}$ by $T(A) = A + A^\mathsf{T} $, where $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$.

a. Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.

b. Let $B$ be any element of $M_{2\times2}$ such that $B^\mathsf{T} = B$. Find an $A$ in $M_{2\times2}$ such that $T(A) = B$.

c. Show that the range of $T$ is the set of $B$ in $M_{2\times2}$ with the property that $B^\mathsf{T} = B$.

d. Describe the kernel of $T$.

$\rule{400pt}{.4pt}$

I was able to find the matrix $A$ for the linear transformation $T$ this way:

$AB = \begin{bmatrix}
2a & b + c \\
b + c & 2d
\end{bmatrix}
$ (by the exercise's definition of $B$ {though it's called "$A$"} and $T$),

$(AB)^\mathsf{T} = B^\mathsf{T}A^\mathsf{T}$,

and then solving two augmented matrices:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & c & 2a\\
b & d & b+c
\end{bmatrix}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 - \frac{c(c-b)}{ad-bc}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{a(c-b)}{ad-bc}
\end{bmatrix}$

(Solving $B^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_1=(\mathbf{ab})^\mathsf{T}_1 $ for $\mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_1$ by row reducing 
$\begin{bmatrix}
B^\mathsf{T} & (\mathbf{ab})^\mathsf{T}_1 
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
I_2 & \mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_1 
\end{bmatrix}$)

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & c & b+c\\
b & d & 2d
\end{bmatrix}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{d(c-b)}{ad-bc}\\
0 & 1 & 2+ \frac{b(c-b)}{ad-bc}
\end{bmatrix}$

(Solving $B^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_2=(\mathbf{ab})^\mathsf{T}_2 $ for $\mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_2$ by row reducing 
$\begin{bmatrix}
B^\mathsf{T} & (\mathbf{ab})^\mathsf{T}_2 
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
I_2 & \mathbf{a}^\mathsf{T}_2 
\end{bmatrix}$)

Ultimately yielding: $$A^\mathsf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 - \frac{c(c-b)}{ad-bc} & -\frac{d(c-b)}{ad-bc} \\
\frac{a(c-b)}{ad-bc} & 2+ \frac{b(c-b)}{ad-bc}
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 - \frac{c(c-b)}{ad-bc} & \frac{a(c-b)}{ad-bc} \\
-\frac{d(c-b)}{ad-bc} & 2+ \frac{b(c-b)}{ad-bc}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\rule{400pt}{.4pt}$

The question I have is how it can be that entries of the matrix $A$ vary due to the entries of the matrix $B$. When I learned the definition of linear transformation, it seemed to be that there must be a matrix $A$ that acts upon every element in the domain to produce the elements in the codomain. Yet, for $B$ with elements $a=d=0$ and $b=-c$, $A$ is the zero transformation, and for $B$ with elements $b=c$, $A$ is $2I_2$. How can I reconcile the fact that this varying $A$ is the matrix of a linear transformation with the fact that, to my knowledge, there must be a single $A$ that is the matrix of a linear transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to speak about the matrix of a linear transformation, you need to fix a basis in the domain and another one in the codomain. In this case, both the domain and the codomain are $M_{2\times2}$ and the canonical basis is $b=\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$, with$$E_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{, }E_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{, }E_{21}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\text{, and }E_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Since $T(E_{11})=2E_{11}$, $T(E_{12})=T(E_{21})=E_{12}+E_{21}$, and $T(E_{22})=2E_{22}$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to $b$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

The answer to your question is: the entries of the matrix of a fixed linear map are fixed numbers.

Comment: The basis has four element, so the matrix of $T$ with respect to $b$ should be of size $4 \times 4$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark Right. Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That looks better! :-)